# 7 pass file erasure

Tags: c++, functional-programming, linux

I am an aspiring C++ programmer and I have been programming for a few years off and on but I don't have much usable knowledge. Right now I am working on filesystem safety so I decided to write an erasure (think BleachBit).

It needs to be run from terminal as such (root/ program filename.something) and needs to open the file in memory, get file size, write in raw binary format to each bit of file, close file,. This is a part where I am stuck. It needs to delete the (I am pretty sure it's some kind of pointer) object that represents
the file that the system stores by wiping it from memory.

ren.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>






void bitwrite(int pass, char * fn)
{
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen(fn, "wb");
    int k;
    const void * kptr;
    switch(pass)
    {
        case 0:
            k = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111;
            break;
        case 1:
            k = 0b10101010101010101010101010101010;
            break;
        case 2:
            k = 0b01010101010101010101010101010101;
            break;
        case 3:
            k = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111;
            break;
        case 4:
            k = 0b10101010101010101010101010101010;
            break;
        case 5:
            k = 0b01010101010101010101010101010101;
            break;
        case 6:
            k = 0b00000000000000000000000000000000;
            break;
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    off_t size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for(int a = 0; a<sizeof(size);a++)
    {   
        fseek(fp, a,  SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&k, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    if(argv == NULL)
    {
        printf("usage: ren file to be destroyed");
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        bitwrite(i, argv[1]);

    }
    printf("success!");

    return 0;
}
```

This code needs to run efficiently as possible. I am at a loss as how to improve and fix errors. Currently, C++ ren.cpp -o ren runs without error, but gdb throws a sigseg error @fseek.

Comment: You forgot to set `fp` before you call fseek. Did you mean for the result of the call to `fopen` to be set to fp?

Comment: i think so? im not fully familiar with file io

Comment: Then there's the effects of caching by the OS., And the (remote) possibility that when you open the file later it might not be written to the same physical location on the disk.  Either one will keep your scheme from working.

Comment: I changed it and now success! prints, it didn't before. now i need to remove the file itself from memory as well as check to make sure the file is actually being modified in memory, and, make the code more efficient , any ideas on how to simplify this code would be great!

Comment: 1201ProgramAlarm what do you mean by that, i am a little new

Comment: the idea is that there is absolutely no trace of the file left that a forensics team would find. i am desperately trying to secure my workspace

Comment: The multi-pass thing does not help on modern drives.  One pass of random data is sufficient.  And it might not work at all, if sector remapping takes place!

Comment: You can not do what you are trying to do from with file system calls (that is a layer of abstraction too far away). The file interface provided by the OS does not give you that much control of how it interacts with the blocks on the disk. You need to look at the block interface provided by your hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `switch`, just use an array.

```
k= pattern[pass];
```

---

Don’t use the C macro `NULL` for any purpose.  Banish it from your memory!

---

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

---

Why are you including `<string>` when you do not use any?  There is nothing at all from the C++ standard library here.  I would think it was a C program.

Comment: <string>is from my last program, can you drop a link to why null is bad?  can you pass on info as to that book and to 'c style'?

Comment: also i need to find an efficient way to unlink the file, truncate it, clear the sys cache and avoid sector remapping? if you have any advice on that please let me know.

Comment: @user171218 not in this Stack.  this is for code reviews.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are off-topic here. This encourages others to continue asking off-topic questions. Instead, you should vote to close.

Comment: @user171218 start with [The Cpre Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md).  I was saying write `myclass* p;` with the `*` hugging the type name.